# Browser back button takes user back inside after Logout

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been working on a web interface using **Flask** and having some issues with **back button** in browser as after logging out hitting it takes user back inside. I have found similar questions and tried their answers but the issue is not resolved. I am attaching a simple example kindly have a look at it.

**Main**

```
from flask import Flask, request,session, redirect, url_for, render_template
from os import urandom

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
app.secret_key = urandom(24)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():

  if request.method == 'POST':
      session['Email id'] = request.form.get('Email Id')
      Pass = request.form.get('Password')
      try:
          if session['Email id'] == 'KK@gmail.com' and Pass == 'KKK':
              return render_template('Logged_in.html')
      except:
          return render_template('login.html')   
  return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/sign_out')
def sign_out():
  session.pop('Email id')
  return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.after_request
def add_header(r):
  r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
  r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"    
  r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
  r.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'    
  return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, threaded=True)
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="POST" id="login" class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Email Id" required name="Email Id">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required name="Password">  
      <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" style="color: white;">Log in</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Logged_in.html**

```
<h2>You are Logged in</h2>
<a href="/sign_out"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Log out</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when users push the back button their browser will re-do  the POST request. You need to use the [POST/redirect/GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to prevent this. For this you need four endpoints in totalt:

1. `GET /` : Check in the session that the user is logged in and render `Logged_in.html`, otherwise redirect to `/login.html`
2. `GET /login.html` : Render `login.html`
3. `POST /sign_in` : Check username and password. If successful, update the session and redirect to `/`
4. `POST /sign_out` : Log out the user session and redirect to `/login.html`

Do not render templates in your POST endpoints, just make them manipulate the session and then redirect.